# Calculus of the integral of the product of the functions $\exp(u^2)$ and $\mbox{erfi}(u^2)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to compute the following integral I(a,b) defined like:
$$I(a,b) = \int_{a}^{b}\mbox{exp}\left(u^{2}\right)\mbox{erfi}\left(u^{2}\right)du$$
with $\mbox{erfi}(x)$ being the imaginary errof function and a and b being real numbers ?
I am studying the following manner:

- using the integral serie of $\exp(u^2)$
- and then a integration by parts of each term of the resulting sum of integrals

In fact, if the path of the integral serie is followed, that leads to this:

$$\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\mbox{erfi}\left(u^{2}\right)du = \int_{a}^{b}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(u^{2}\right)^{k}}{k!}\mbox{erfi}\left(u^{2}\right)du$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\int_{a}^{b}u^{2k}\mbox{erfi}\left(u^{2}\right)du$$

Using the serie development of the function $erfi(x)$ that is:
$$erfi(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2j+1}}{j!\left(2j+1\right)}$$
gives then:

$$\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\mbox{erfi}\left(u^{2}\right)du=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\int_{a}^{b}u^{2k}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^{4j+2}}{j!\left(2j+1\right)}du$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{j!\left(2j+1\right)}\int_{a}^{b}u^{2k+4j+2}du$$

Given that $\int_{a}^{b}u^{2k+4j+2}du=\left[\frac{u^{2k+4j+3}}{2k+4j+3}\right]_{a}^{b}=\frac{b^{2k+4j+3}-a^{2k+4j+3}}{2k+4j+3}$, this yields a result in the form of a double sum:
$$\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\mbox{erfi}\left(u^{2}\right)du=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{j!\left(2j+1\right)}\left(\frac{b^{2k+4j+3}-a^{2k+4j+3}}{2k+4j+3}\right)$$
which i am not totally satisfied of because it means a not so light implementation.

Any other idea ?

Comment: One first path is to use a change of variable $x=u^2$ and then the development of the exponential into its integral serie to"marry" it with the $\frac{1}{2\sqrt(x)}$ resulting from the variable change. Then we will obtain a infinite discrete sum of integrals. Each of this integral will be the one of the product of a monome and the erfi function. Right ?

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? Since ${t}$ is not present within the integral?

Comment: What is your intended meaning of "compute".  Your integrand contains transcendental functions, and evaluating those already involves limit operations.

Comment: What is the purpose of all of your comments to your own post? You are not responding to anyone, and it looks to me like they are supposed to be your own efforts at the problem, in which case it should belong in the post so that they can be easily seen. Likewise, your edit to the post seems to be a reply to a comment. Such comments belong in the comments, not in your post.

Comment: @EricTowers My purpose is to get an implementable calculus. While speaking only of math, we may consider, for example, a common integral to be a solution, but while speaking at the same time in terms of programmatical usability, i prefer to develop the calculus until the implementation of the calculus becomes crystal-clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maclaurin series of $J(x) = \int_0^x \exp(u^2) \text{erfi}(u^2)\; du$ is
$$ J(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^{3+2k} $$
where $a_0 = 2/3$, $a_1 = 2/5$, $a_2 = 5/21$, $a_3 = 1/9$ and for $n \ge 4$,
$$ a_n = \frac{4n+2}{2n^2 + 5 n + 3} a_{n-1} + \frac{4n^2-8n+3}{2n^3+5n^2+3n} a_{n-2} + \frac{-4n+6}{2n^3+5n^2+3n} a_{n-3}$$

Comment: Any more hint about how you obtain the Mac Laurin Serie of $J(x)$, or is this a classic result of integral calculus (any link to the proof ?) I check the first terms of my own double sum and it seems to be ok, but do the two results coincide ? Anyway, thanks for the answer !

Comment: You can derive it from the differential equation satisfied by $y(t) = \exp(t) \text{erfi}(t)$: 
$y'' - (2 t + 2) y' + (2 t + 1) y = 0$.

Comment: Right. But what do you think of my double sum result ?